# i get error 404 not found

Tags: magento-1.9, error, 404-page

I changed the password of my Magento backend. 
Too many people knew the password so I changed it.

I wanted to install magento extension notification bar in the Magento Connect Manager.
After the installation Magento went into maintenance mode
Then I deleted the maintenance flag and after that I am gettting the 404 error.

what to do? i cant login to the admin area and also i get the error on all pages

need your help.

Comment: you can´t login anymore or you get a 404 on the extension tab?

like this http://www.fanplayr.com/1415/magento-404-error-page-not-found-in-configuration/

Comment: i cant login @Thomas

Comment: can you login then again?

Comment: I deleted the extension from app/etc/modules/ fix the problem, i go to the magento connect manager to delete also from there but now i get error 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable, i think the trigger Maintenance mode was to enable Put store on the maintenance mode while backup creation was enable what to do now?

Comment: now i get error 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable same thing i cant login, i try to find in the root maintenance.flag But there is no such file what to do? @Thomas

Comment: i found the Maintenance file and now i can login, how to delete the extension from the connect manager? thx for the help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T63JZNT9MM8